# Ordenar arraylist por criterio especificado?

Tags: java, ordenar

tengo este ejercicio

"Realiza un programa Java que lea los datos 5 alumnos. Para cada alumno se tiene la siguiente
información: Nia(entero), Nombre(String), Apellidos(String), Sexo (Char), Ciclo (String),
Curso(String), Grupo(String).

**a raiz de esto, yo estoy haciendo la actividad opcional 2:**

**Actividad opcional 2:** Mostrar los alumnos por el criterio que se elija por teclado. Deberás
hacer un menú con las opciones de leer alumnos (leerá 5), añadir alumno, mostrar alumno
por NIA, y mostrar alumno por el criterio elegido por el usuario

"

Bueno pues he hecho el objeto Alumno;

```
package primeraevaluacion;

public class Alumno implements Comparable<Alumno>{
    
    int Nia;
    String Nombre;
    String Apellidos;
    char Sexo;
    String Ciclo;
    String Curso;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno [Nia=" + Nia + ", Nombre=" + Nombre + ", Apellidos=" + Apellidos + ", Sexo=" + Sexo + ", Ciclo="
                + Ciclo + ", Curso=" + Curso + ", Grupo=" + Grupo + "]";
    }

    String Grupo;

    public Alumno(int Nia, String Nombre, String Apellidos, char sexo, String Ciclo, String Curso,
            String Grupo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        
        this.Nia=Nia;
        this.Nombre=Nombre;
        this.Apellidos=Apellidos;
        this.Sexo=sexo;
        this.Ciclo=Ciclo;
        this.Curso=Curso;
        this.Grupo=Grupo;
        
        
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Alumno o) {
        if (o.getNia() > Nia) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o.getNia()> Nia) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
        
    }
    
    

    public int getNia() {
        return Nia;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return Apellidos;
    }

    public char getSexo() {
        return Sexo;
    }

    public String getCiclo() {
        return Ciclo;
    }

    public String getCurso() {
        return Curso;
    }

    public String getGrupo() {
        return Grupo;
    }

    
}
```

y luego la clase donde hago las operaciones:

```
package primeraevaluacion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import utilidades.Entrada;

public class P01_tarea1opcional2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Alumno> al = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
        ArrayList<Alumno> alordenada= new ArrayList<Alumno>();
        int entradanumero;
        String criterio;
        
        int Nia;
        String Nombre;
        String Apellidos;
        char Sexo;
        String Ciclo;
        String Curso;
        String Grupo;
        
        
        boolean salida=false;
        do {
            System.out.println("===MENU ALUMNOS====");
            System.out.println("0 -Salir");
            System.out.println("1 -Leer alumnos");
            System.out.println("2 -Añadir alumno");
            System.out.println("3 -Mostrar alumno por NIA");
            entradanumero=Entrada.entero();
            
            switch (entradanumero) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Adios");
                break;

            case 1:
                if (al.size() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("La lista de alumnos está vacia, pulse la tecla 2 para añadir alumno");
                } else {
                    for (Alumno alumno : al) {
                        System.out.println(alumno);
                    }
                }
                
                break;
                
            case 2:
                if (al.size() < 5) {
                    
                    System.out.println("Introduzca NIA: ");
                    Nia=Entrada.entero();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Nombre: ");
                    Nombre=Entrada.cadena();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Apellido: ");
                    Apellidos=Entrada.cadena();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Sexo: (H o M)");
                    Sexo=Entrada.caracter();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Ciclo: ");
                    Ciclo=Entrada.cadena();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Curso: ");
                    Curso=Entrada.cadena();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Grupo: ");
                    Grupo=Entrada.cadena();
                    
                    al.add(new Alumno(Nia,Nombre,Apellidos,Sexo,Ciclo,Curso,Grupo));
                    alordenada.add(new Alumno(Nia,Nombre,Apellidos,Sexo,Ciclo,Curso,Grupo));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Alumnos llenos");
                }
                
                
                
                break;
                
            case 3:
                Collections.sort(alordenada);
                for (Alumno alumno : alordenada) {
                    System.out.println(alumno);
                }
                break;
                
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Por cual Criterio quieres ordenar?");
                criterio=Entrada.cadena();
                
                switch (criterio) {
                case "Nia":
                    
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Criterio incorrecto");
                    break;
                }
                
                break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("Numero incorrecto");
                break;
            }
            
        } while (entradanumero!=0);
        
    
        

        
        
        
        
    }

    
}
```

Y el problema lo tengo, en que yo no sé mostrar el alumno por el criterio elegido por el usuario, en el switch habia indicado "Por cual Criterio quieres ordenar?" pero no sé si tengo que hacer algo con el collections, o un compare to distinto. Muchas gracias

Comment: Probalo de ambas maneras, y fijate cuál te parece más práctico :) Estás encaminado, solo te falta implementar lo que estás pensando.

Comment: Si la cosa es, que no se implementarlo, por eso pregunto y ver si alguien me da algun fragmento de codigo, porque ahora mismo no se me ocurre, jajaj un saludo, ya que no me acuerdo de usar el collections.sort

Comment: Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código... Hay [varios](https://www.bezkoder.com/java-sort-arraylist-of-objects/) [sitios](https://www.javadevjournal.com/java/java-sorting-example-comparable-comparator/) en internet que ya responden a tu pregunta. Recuerda que preguntar aquí debe ser _tu último recurso_.

Comment: Y por eso estoy preguntando aquí, por que no tengo ni idea, la documentación no va al grano y es extensa, y stack overflow es mi salvación, un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir de java 8+ podes usar el metodo [comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) el cual compara los objetos por una clave de ordenación

```
//por nia
Comparator<Alumno> cm1=Comparator.comparing(Alumno::getNia);  
Collections.sort(nombreDeLista,cm1); 


//por nombre al ser de tipo String le agregamos String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER para que ignore  las diferencias entre mayúsculas y minúsculassi existiera el caso
Comparator<Alumno> cm2=Comparator.comparing(Alumno::getNombre,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);  
Collections.sort(lista,cm2);
```

ahora solo debes adaptarlo a un switch con otras claves de ordenación ;)

Comment: Sigo sin ver la respuesta, no entiendo nada y no se donde tengo que implementarlo

Comment: Vale!! creo que lo estoy pillando, los estoy poniendo en el main, y me va funcionando ahora edito, es que madre mia, esto del collections lo uso poco y soy de estresarme facilmente

Comment: Vale!! creo que lo estoy pillando, los estoy poniendo en el main, y me va funcionando ahora edito, es que madre mia, esto del collections lo uso poco y soy de estresarme facilmente

Comment: Dios listo, ya esta muchas gracias, he estado toda esta semana intentando entenderlo, JAJAJA muchas gracias

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha resultado útil, te ruego que la marques como aceptada, de ese modo la pregunta queda marcada como "respondida" y ambos usuarios sois recompensados con unos puntos extra de reputación :)

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo hice asi **NOTA**: no estan todas las validaciones asi que puede dar error:

Clase de las operaciones:

```
package primeraevaluacion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import utilidades.Entrada;

public class P01_tarea1opcional2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Alumno> al = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
        ArrayList<Alumno> alordenada= new ArrayList<Alumno>();
        
        
        Comparator<Alumno> cm1=Comparator.comparing(Alumno::getNia);   //Ordenar por nia
        
        Comparator<Alumno> cm2=Comparator.comparing(Alumno::getNombre,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);   // Ordenar por nombre
        
        Comparator<Alumno> cm3=Comparator.comparing(Alumno::getApellidos,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);  // Ordenar por apellido
        
        Comparator<Alumno> cm4=Comparator.comparing(Alumno::getSexo); // Ordenar por sexo
        
        Comparator<Alumno> cm5=Comparator.comparing(Alumno::getCiclo,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // Ordenado por Ciclo
        
        Comparator<Alumno> cm6=Comparator.comparing(Alumno::getCurso,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // Ordenador por Curso
        
        Comparator<Alumno> cm7=Comparator.comparing(Alumno::getGrupo,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); // Ordenado por grupo
        
        int entradanumero;
        String criterio;
        Alumno aux = new Alumno();      
        int Nia;
        String Nombre;
        String Apellidos;
        char Sexo;
        String Ciclo;
        String Curso;
        String Grupo;
        
        
        boolean salida=false;
        do {
            System.out.println("===MENU ALUMNOS====");
            System.out.println("0 -Salir");
            System.out.println("1 -Leer alumnos");
            System.out.println("2 -Añadir alumno");
            System.out.println("3 -Mostrar alumno por NIA");
            System.out.println("4 -Mostrar alumno por Criterio especifico");
            entradanumero=Entrada.entero();
            
            switch (entradanumero) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Adios");
                break;

            case 1:
                if (al.size() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("La lista de alumnos está vacia, pulse la tecla 2 para añadir alumno");
                } else {
                    for (Alumno alumno : al) {
                        System.out.println(alumno);
                    }
                }
                
                break;
                
            case 2:
                if (al.size() < 5) {
                    
                    
                    System.out.println("Introduzca NIA: ");
                    Nia=Entrada.entero();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Nombre: ");
                    Nombre=Entrada.cadena();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Apellido: ");
                    Apellidos=Entrada.cadena();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Sexo: (H o M)");
                    Sexo=Entrada.caracter();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Ciclo: ");
                    Ciclo=Entrada.cadena();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Curso: ");
                    Curso=Entrada.cadena();
                    System.out.println("Introduzca Grupo: ");
                    Grupo=Entrada.cadena();
                    
                    al.add(new Alumno(Nia,Nombre,Apellidos,Sexo,Ciclo,Curso,Grupo));
                    alordenada.add(new Alumno(Nia,Nombre,Apellidos,Sexo,Ciclo,Curso,Grupo));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Alumnos llenos");
                }
                
                
                
                break;
                
            case 3:
                Collections.sort(alordenada,cm1); 
                for (Alumno alumno : alordenada) {
                    System.out.println(alumno);
                }
                break;
                
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Por cual Criterio quieres ordenar?");
                criterio=Entrada.cadena();
                
                switch (criterio) {
                case "Nia":
                    Collections.sort(alordenada,cm1); 
                    for (Alumno alumno : alordenada) {
                        System.out.println(alumno);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Nombre":
                    Collections.sort(alordenada, cm2);
                    for (Alumno alumno : alordenada) {
                        System.out.println(alumno);
                    }
                    
                    break;
                    
                case "Apellidos":
                    Collections.sort(alordenada, cm3);
                    for (Alumno alumno : alordenada) {
                        System.out.println(alumno);
                    }
                    
                    break;
                    
                case "Sexo":
                    Collections.sort(alordenada, cm4);
                    for (Alumno alumno : alordenada) {
                        System.out.println(alumno);
                    }
                    
                    break;
                    
                case "Ciclo":
                    Collections.sort(alordenada, cm5);
                    for (Alumno alumno : alordenada) {
                        System.out.println(alumno);
                    }
                    
                    break;
                    
                case "Curso":
                    Collections.sort(alordenada, cm6);
                    for (Alumno alumno : alordenada) {
                        System.out.println(alumno);
                    }
                    
                    break;
                    
                case "Grupo":
                    Collections.sort(alordenada, cm7);
                    for (Alumno alumno : alordenada) {
                        System.out.println(alumno);
                    }
                    
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Criterio incorrecto");
                    break;
                }
                
                break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("Numero incorrecto");
                break;
            }
            
        } while (entradanumero!=0);
        
    
        

        
        
        
        
    }

    
}
```

Clase Alumno:

```
package primeraevaluacion;

public class Alumno implements Comparable<Alumno>{
    
    int Nia;
    public String Nombre;
    String Apellidos;
    char Sexo;
    String Ciclo;
    String Curso;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno [Nia=" + Nia + ", Nombre=" + Nombre + ", Apellidos=" + Apellidos + ", Sexo=" + Sexo + ", Ciclo="
                + Ciclo + ", Curso=" + Curso + ", Grupo=" + Grupo + "]";
    }

    String Grupo;

    public Alumno(int Nia, String Nombre, String Apellidos, char sexo, String Ciclo, String Curso,
            String Grupo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        
        this.Nia=Nia;
        this.Nombre=Nombre;
        this.Apellidos=Apellidos;
        this.Sexo=sexo;
        this.Ciclo=Ciclo;
        this.Curso=Curso;
        this.Grupo=Grupo;
        
        
        
        
    }

    public Alumno() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Alumno o) {
        if (o.getNia() > Nia) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o.getNia()> Nia) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
        
    }
    
    

    public int getNia() {
        return Nia;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return Apellidos;
    }

    public char getSexo() {
        return Sexo;
    }

    public String getCiclo() {
        return Ciclo;
    }

    public String getCurso() {
        return Curso;
    }

    public String getGrupo() {
        return Grupo;
    }

    
}
```

Comment: buena implementacion , ten presente que ya no es necesario el metodo compareTo ni el implements Comparable en la clase Alumno ;),si la respuesta te ah sido de utilidad recuerda marcar el icono de ✓ ,saludos

Comment: Es que en mi clase lo que hacen que no se hacer yo es hacer varias clases de compareto para los distintos criterios, entonces bueno, esto me ha servido mientras tanto, gracias